# Cant delete XmlElement using Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a very basic linq query to be able to delete one node from xml file.But when ı run this code I am  getting this exception below.

```
 Sequence contains no elements
```

then I have used FirstOrDefault() instead First()  ( as mentioned earlier posts) and this time Exection message turned into this

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Kitaplar.xml"));
        var toDelete = (from data in doc.Elements("Kitap") where data.Attribute("id").Value == "1" select data).FirstOrDefault();
        toDelete.Remove();
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("Kitaplar.xml"));

    }
```

And this is the xmlfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Kitaplar>
  <Kitap id="1">
    <Kitapadi>asasa</Kitapadi>
    <Yazar>sasas</Yazar>
    <Sayfa>22</Sayfa>
  </Kitap>
  <Kitap id="2">
    <Kitapadi>jhjh</Kitapadi>
    <Yazar>kjkj</Yazar>
    <Sayfa>33</Sayfa>
  </Kitap>
  <Kitap id="3">
    <Kitapadi>lkjhg</Kitapadi>
    <Yazar>gffd</Yazar>
    <Sayfa>988</Sayfa>
  </Kitap>

  <Kitap id="4">
    <Kitapadi>lkjhg</Kitapadi>
    <Yazar>gffd</Yazar>
    <Sayfa>988</Sayfa>
  </Kitap>
</Kitaplar>
```

Everyting looks ok to me.what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Debug through your program. Does `doc` get filled with an actual file?

Comment: Use `from data in doc.Root.Elements(...`. Your `doc` variable points to document representation, whose first element is `Kitaplar` node (root element).

Comment: You are right jimmy. It works this way. @Matthijs thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of writing a method that takes the file, element and ID; then removes the Element accordingly.

```
private bool DeleteRowWithID(string fileName, string element, string id)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        if (doc.Root == null)
            return false;

        XElement toRemove = doc.Root.Elements(element).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (toRemove == null)
            return false;

        toRemove.Remove();
        doc.Save(fileName);

        return true;
    }
```

Above method loads the XmlDocument in an XDocument (which allows LINQ to XML). It checks if the root isn't empty, then finds the element you specified.

It checks if the element exists; then removes that element from the document, and save the made removal.

Last, it returns true to indicate that the element has actually been removed.

If you just want the element and stick to your method, use the following:

```
XElement toRemove = doc.Root.Elements("Kitap").Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "1").FirstOrDefault();
```